# Akka: Simple Akka Cluster not working.

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

We are creating simple akka cluster sample and follow `Akka In Action` book. we are creating 3 seed nodes as mention in following code:

```
akka {

  loglevel = INFO
  stdout-loglevel = INFO
  event-handlers = ["akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger"]
  log-dead-letters = 0
  log-dead-letters-during-shutdown = off

  actor {
    provider = cluster
  }

  remote {
    enabled-transport = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      hostname = ${?HOST}
      port = ${?PORT}
    }
  }

  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka.tcp://words@127.0.0.1:2551",
      "akka.tcp://words@127.0.0.1:2552",
      "akka.tcp://words@127.0.0.1:2553"
    ]

    roles = ["seed"]

    role {
      seed.min-nr-of-members = 1
    }
  }
}
```

Actor system code:

```
object Launcher extends App {

  val seedConfig = ConfigFactory.load("seed")
  val seedSystem = ActorSystem("words", seedConfig)
}
```

When start actor system from one terminal, the seed node load but according to logs, port `2552` is used but my expectations are `2551`. After opening second terminal when trying to run again actor system, I am facing following exception:

```
[ERROR] [03/10/2017 15:51:45.245] [words-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-13] [NettyTransport(akka://words)] failed to bind to /127.0.0.1:2552, shutting down Netty transport
[error] (run-main-0) org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /127.0.0.1:2552
org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /127.0.0.1:2552
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
    at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport.$anonfun$listen$1(NettyTransport.scala:417)
    at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:251)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:209)
```

This error is generate because, in first terminal our port `2552` is used but not sure why second time same port is use. Our assumptions are, maybe configurations is not loaded. So, how we can fix this ?

Comment: And how do you pick your port? From `.env` file?

Comment: I have not any `.env` file in my example @BranislavLazic

Comment: Ok. So how's your port set?

Comment: @BranislavLazic I am just define in application.conf as above and run on terminal by using following command `sbt -DHOST=127.0.0.1 -DPORT=2551` for all three ports.

Comment: Try `-Dakka.remote.netty.tcp.port=2551` instead and tell me what happens.

Comment: @BranislavLazic I am using command `sbt -DHOST=127.0.0.1 -Dakka.remote.netty.tcp.port=2551` and in second terminal using `sbt run` for running my main class, but still the same thing happens, by defaul, `2552` post is used instead of `2551`.